# Declarative input language strategies

Tags: design, declarative-programming

I need to develop a simple declarative language to drive an application. I have various computational modules, some of them depending on other modules which also need setup. The problem is that I don't know how to manipulate the keywords. I will explain myself with an example

```
Task optimize
Units meters
System {
   // input data
}

Optimizer {
     type Simplex
     convergenceCriteria 0.001
}

PointEvaluator {
     type MyEvaluatorTechnique
     convergenceCriteria = 0.1
}
```

this is a solution, which has header very generic entities which describe the meaning of each section, but I could also have sections that explicity concern specific techniques

```
Task {
     type optimize
     optimizer Simplex
}
Units meters
System {
   // input data
}

Simplex {
     convergenceCriteria 0.001
     PointEvaluator MyEvaluatorTechnique
}

MyEvaluatorTechnique {
     convergenceCriteria = 0.1
}
```

I would like to hear your opinion on which method may sound better in terms of design correctness, and pros and cons of both solutions. One thing I don't like in the first solution is, for example, the fact that depending on the type, I may have options that do not make sense for that specific type. In the second solution, however, I am setting up not the generic task (which then uses specific types of subsystem). Instead, I specify the specific subsystems performing the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Designing DSL's is hard.

So hard, that I suggest that you avoid it until you are compelled to create the DSL.

My suggestion is this.

1. Create a proper class hierarchy.
2. Create pleasant, easy-to-use initializers and constants.
3. Get things to work as simple object construction.

Later, after things work, and after you see what the DSL must express, consider designing a DSL.

Some class Definitions.

```
class  Task( object ):
    pass

class Optimizer( Task ):
    def __init__( self, optimizer ):
        pass

class Simplex( object ):
    def __init__( self, evaluator ):

class Evaluator( object ):
    def __init__( self, convergence ):
         pass

class MyEvaluatorTechnique( Evaluator ):
    pass
```

A Configuration

```
config = Optimizer( 
    Simplex(), 
    MyEvaluatorTechnique( convergence=0.001 ) 
)
```

This avoids a lot of complexity of writing a parser and handling keywords.  Instead, you use the parser for another language (i.e. Python or Java or Lua or something)

Comment: I read your blog post on this same topic. I did realize that declarative style is hard, and we are in fact probably planning to switch to an imperative style. For the moment, however, I must implement a declarative style.

Comment: +1 for Lua. This use case is more-or-less exactly what Lua was designed for from the ground up. That it is a pretty excellent and fast little language is a real bonus.

Comment: +1 for Lua idem. Even older versions, like Lua 4 could handle these type of requirements easy.

Comment: @Stefano Borini:  This is declarative.